# How to change link for each item in foreach loop in PHP?

Tags: php

Totally no experience with PHP and I need to change some little thing by my self, the developer has made a generic html component with a generic link ("href=#"). This should be different for each item in foreach loop. Pretty simple but totally difficult who doesnt know the syntax.

Anyone a quick fix?

```
<?php foreach ($pricing['price_box'] as $box) :?>
    <div class="col-lg-6 mb-4 mb-lg-0">
        <div class="p-4 pl-5 pr-5 pb-5">
            <h3 class="text-center pt-4 pb-5"><?php echo $box['title'] ?></h3>
            <div class="d-md-flex justify-content-md-between mb-5">
                <?php echo $box['detail'] ?>
                <div class="price-unit align-self-center">
                    <?php
                    $priceArray = explode('.', $box['price']);
                    echo $box['price'] ? $priceArray[0] . ",<span>$priceArray[1]</span>" : ''
                    ?>
                    <div><?php echo $box['duration'] ?></div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="text-center">
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary arrow-icon">Registreren</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: You will have to describe EXACTLY what you want to change, from what to what?

Comment: You need to know array structure so simple create an HTML link with (i suppose) link ID

Comment: Where is the link supposed to come from? Is it part of `$pricing['price_box']`? What  does `print_r($pricing['price_box']); die();` output?

Answer (score 1):

Since the anchor tag is inside the `foreach` loop, you can use the `$box` variable in the anchor tag.

Also, you can use the php variable inside the html by `echo` it.

For example, if your link is something like `some_php_script.php?id=XXX` and you want to replace the `xxx` with a unique `id`, you can use it like:

```php
<a href="some_php_script.php?id=<?php echo $box['id'];?>" class="btn btn-primary arrow-icon">Registreren</a>
```

*assumes that the `$box` array contains an index called `id`.*

> Read more about [php echo](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.echo.php) function.
>   Read more about php arrays [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php).

Comment: This wont work, since there is no ID in my link.

I just want for the first item href=google.com and for second item href=google.nl, so totally different links without ID's in it and purely based on the index number of the item.

Comment: Just demonstrated how to use a php variable in html. Now, tell us what is your logic to generate the links? Is it anything based on the $pricing array?

Comment: Thanks for the demo, the logic is, for price 1 there is a link1 and for price 2 there is a link2. just this nothing special, i just want to forward the user to a different registration page from each price.

Comment: I don't think it would be a good idea to have this redirection. Because the prices could be change from the data base and you should specify new links for each price. 

It would be better if you can have a single page that takes the price as an argument and then do the action based on that price. 

I have edited my answer in with this logic.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you need to change the link here :

```
<div class="text-center">
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary arrow-icon">Registreren</a>
</div>
```

As it is already in the loop, and you have `$box` array, you need to find out on which `index` the link `href` and text(the one you need to display instead of `Registreren` ) is available. Suppose you have the link at index `link` and text is at `text`, then your code will be like

```
<div class="text-center">
    <a href=<?php echo $box['link'];?> class="btn btn-primary arrow-icon"><?php echo $box['text'];?></a>
</div>
```

You can check the array structure using `print_r()`

Reference

[Arrays](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php)

[foreach](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php)

Comment: This wont work, since there is no ID in my link.

I just want for the first item href=google.com and for second item href=google.nl, so totally different links without ID's in it and purely based on the index number of the item.

Comment: There is no ``id` here in the answer. You might be referring the wrong answer. Anyway, I think you got the idea and the syntax.